# Accepting all parameters in phpsepc2 mocks

Tags: phpspec

How i can accept all parameters in function mock with #phpspec2?

for example i have code like this:

```
$em->persist($entity)->willReturn(true);
```

I don't want mock all possible parameters, it should accept every entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Argument` class and `any` method/function:

```
use Prophecy\Argument;
...
Argument::any()
```

[Here](https://github.com/phpspec/prophecy/blob/master/src/Prophecy/Argument.php#L77) you can find more details about this.